# Send push notification from iOS using Amazon SNS

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I set it up Amazon SNS and iOS App to send Push Notification via SNS Console and receive in iOS. It works properly.

Now, I'm trying to send push notification from a device to another device, but I'm getting the following error:

> -[AWSServiceInfo initWithInfoDictionary:checkRegion:] | Couldn't read credentials provider configurations from `Info.plist`. Please check
>   your `Info.plist` if you are providing the SDK configuration values
>   through `Info.plist`.

There's my code to send push notification

```
AWSSNS *publishCall = [AWSSNS defaultSNS];

AWSSNSPublishInput *message = [AWSSNSPublishInput new];

message.subject = @"My First Message";


//This is the ending point
message.targetArn = @"arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:895047407854:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/XXXXX/XXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXX";
message.subject =@"hello";
message.message =@"teste from device";
//    message.messageAttributes = messageDict;
//
//    message.messageStructure = jsonString;

    [publishCall publish:message completionHandler:^(AWSSNSPublishResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(error) NSLog(@"%@", [error userInfo]);
        if(response) NSLog(@"%@", [response description]);
    }];
```

I don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the debug log of `AWSInfo.m` [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSCore/Service/AWSInfo.m) you will get this error when you have not configured your `defaultCognitoCredentialsProvider`

As they will check

```
_cognitoCredentialsProvider = [AWSInfo defaultAWSInfo].defaultCognitoCredentialsProvider;
```

if they find `_cognitoCredentialsProvider` nil then you will get this error.

So configure `defaultCognitoCredentialsProvider` properly.

Comment: Now the error changed to `not authorized to perform: SNS:Publish on resource: arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXX:app/APNS_SANDBOX/XXXXXX<`

Comment: That error says you are not able to perform this action, you need to check your permissions

Comment: Where can I check my permissions?

Comment: Check this - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/sns-topic-policy.html

Comment: thanks! I did check the documentation and add role to publishing :D